# Find constant $c$ where joint p.d.f is $f(x,y)=cx^2yI_{x^2\le y\le 1}$

Tags: probability

Find the value of constant c when the joint p.d.f of X and Y is specified as follows.
$$f(x,y)=cx^2yI_{x^2\le y\le 1}$$
I found the solution from textbook but I don't understand why my solution is incorrect.

**My solution**
$$\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y}cx^2ydxdy=\int_0^1\left.(c/3)x^3y\right\rvert_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y}dy=(2/3)c$$
$$(2/3)c=1$$
$$c=3/2$$
When I saw the graph about region of $(x,y)$, the solution of the answer sheet is understood, but I can not induce it in terms of integral using my own intuition.

**Solution from answer sheet**
$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{x^2}^1cx^2ydydx=c(4/21)=1$$
$$c=21/4$$

Comment: Whats the solution of answer sheet?

Comment: @GuillermoGarcíaSáez I added it to the post

Comment: You should integrate from $-\sqrt{y}$ to $\sqrt{y}$ and it should integrate to $4c/21$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of bound is well done, but you integrated wrong.
$$\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^\sqrt{y}x^2ydxdy=\int_0^1\frac{2y^{3/2}}{3}ydy=\int_0^1\frac{2y^{5/2}}{3}dy=\frac{4}{21},\implies c=\frac{21}{4}.$$

Comment: Indeed. Forgive me for taking your time. Excessive cramming gave me a hard time.

Comment: Don't mind. It's a pleasure to help :)